# Calculation of apparent heating (Q1) and apparent moisture sink (Q2) as defined by Yanai et al. (1972) using NetCDF data?

Tags: meteorology, mesoscale-meteorology

Please can anyone explain how to calculate apparent heating (Q1) and apparent moisture sink (Q2) as defined by Yanai et al. (1972) using NetCDF data?

Please kindly check equation 6(Q1) and 7(Q2) of the paper via this link (http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0469(1973)030%3C0611:DOBPOT%3E2.0.CO;2). I would like to use variables in the left hand side of the equations to solve for the Q1 and Q2.

I would prefer to get the explanation in NCL or any other language.

Thanks.

Comment: not sure what the problem is. The parameters are given. It is just numerical differentiation. Continuity equation

Comment: Thanks gansub for your response. Please could you kindly describe how I can calculate each of the terms using numerical differentiation? Thank you.

Comment: Please see this new NCL function that calculate q1 and q2 [link1](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Scripts/Q1Q2_yanai_1.ncl) which is described at thee end of [this page](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/wind.shtml)